# Button onclick doesnot print anything wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Button onclick doesnot print anything I need help to print the content on wordpress

on header.php I place this

```
<script>

$('.print-button').on('click', function() {  
  window.print();  
  return false;
});

<script>
```

and inside anything popup plugin's text i write this

```
<button class="print-button">Print this page</button>
```

But It doesn't print anything please help

Comment: is print dialog appears?

Comment: no nothing appears

Comment: Put your script before the closing of `</body>` tag

Comment: can you write the complete script please that will be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your jquery code inside jquery's onload:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('.print-button').on('click', function() {  
      window.print();  
    });    
  });
<script>
```

You should probably also give the button the type `button`, to omit any possible unwanted side effects if the button get's placed inside a form or similar:

```
<button class="print-button" type="button">Print this page</button>
```

Read more about it here: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: where to place the script on header or  footer and button is inside anything popup plugin's

Comment: The script can basically be placed anywhere. What do you mean with _"and button is inside anything popup plugin's"_? You need to tell us all the details.

Comment: It prints the complete page I want to print the content inside popup only

Comment: Just add a print.css where you hide everything that shouldn't be printed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have trouble in making the print button to work, do these,

**1. Inline Way:**

```
<button class="print-button" onclick="window.print()">Print this page</button>
```

**2. Move script to bottom**

```
<body>
   ...
   ...
   ...
   <script href="jquery.js"></script>
   <script>
       $('.print-button').on('click', function() {  
         window.print();  
       }); 
   </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `jQuery` in place of `$` and use wordpress hooks to add javascript. put this code inside your theme `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function(){
?>
 <script>

   jQuery(document).on('click', '.print-button', function() {  
    window.print();  
    return false;
  });

<script>
<?php
});
```

Comment: If the OP adds the JS-code in the header or footer in the theme, there's no need to add it in any hook. You should really not add JS like that anyway. You should rather create a js-file which you load using `wp_enqueue_script()`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson of course I used this code snippet to add internal js and css because i don't want to ask server to make a new request to load js and css file with 2 or 3 lines of code.

Comment: Then you might as well put it in the header or footer file directly instead of adding js and css using PHP.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes I'm totally agree with you, but sometime its overhead the developer, as a developer point of view I personally not interested to update the theme file as we got the theme update.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
   $.noConflict();
   jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.print-button').on('click', function() {  
      window.print();  
    });    
  });
</script>
```

Comment: A good answer contains an _explanation_, like what you've changed and why, and not just a chunk of code.